# How to start ipsec on Gentoo after migrated to systemd?

Tags: gentoo, systemd, ipsec

My system is Gentoo 64bit, and is using *systemd* as the initialization system. After I migrated to systemd, I found there's not service to start **ipsec**. I tried to run `/etc/init.d/ipsec`, but it says it would only work with *openrc*.

What is the corresponding service to start *ipsec*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the service file actually exists, you should be able to launch it with `systemctl start ipsec`. You'll need the appropriate USE flags for systemd as well, probably -- I'd suggest a systemd subprofile if you're not already using one.

Comment: i have installed the package. but the challenge is the service is not exist. and i have not idea how to set up this service by manual.

Comment: @davidshen84 Which USE flags did you use when installing the ipsec-tools package?

Comment: I did not install the ipsec-tools package. On Gentoo, it is the `openswan` package that provides the ipsec service. At least it was...